# Proper way to transfer user profile from Win 8.1 to Win 10?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, user-profiles

I am replacing some of my coworker's computers. The old computers have Windows 8.1 and the new computers have Windows 10. In the past when both computers had Windows 8.1 I would just copy the entire user profile (C:\users\SomeUser) from the old machine to the new. Windows 8.1 would pick up the profile just fine. Now with Windows 10, when the user signs in to their new computer, a new profile is made instead (C:\users\SomeUser.Domain). How do I avoid that?

Comment: Its not clear what you want to try to avoid.  [`Laplink PCmover Express`](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/en-gb/xp/transfer-your-data.aspx) is the "official" way to do it on Windows 10  Honestly it sounds like your user is part of a domain.

Comment: Yes, we are on a domain. I am trying to avoid a new, empty profile from being created. Instead I would like it to grab and use the profile that was copied over from Window 8.1. It is a relatively simple task to copy stuff from C:\users\someuser to c:\users\someuser.domain, but I didn't have to do that when going from 8.1 to 8.1.

Comment: Were you always on a domain?

Comment: Yes. We have always been on a domain. We are subcontractors for a much larger organization. None of us are domain admins, but I am a local admin on everyone's machine. Yes, backing stuff up to OneDrive for Business and letting it sync would be the best method, just like cats that would follow orders would make them easier to herd. Unfortunately, we don't live in such a world.